# Linear Operator $T:X\to Y$, where $X$ is Banach. Is $T$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces and $X$ a Banach one and let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear operator. Also suppose that there exists a sequence of closed subsets of $X$, $\left \{ F_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$, such that $ X= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n $ and $T(F_n)$ be a bounded subset of $Y$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I want to show that the operator $T$ is bounded.

From Baire Category Theorem we obtain that $ \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}:int(F_{n_0})\neq 0 $, therefore $\exists y\in F_{n_0} \exists \epsilon >0: B(y,\epsilon)\subseteq F_{n_0}$ and so $T(B(y,\epsilon))$ is bounded.

Now if we suppose that $T$ is not bounded then we conclude that $T$ is not continuous on $y$ and so $\exists \epsilon >0 \ \ \exists (x_n)\in X^{\mathbb{N}}: ||x_n-y||\to 0(\Leftrightarrow x_n\to y)$ and $||Tx_n-y||\geq \epsilon$.

I cannot go any further and I don't know if I am getting somewhere through this.

Comment: $T(B(y,\varepsilon)) = T(y + B(\varepsilon)) = Ty + T(B(\varepsilon))$. Does that help?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I cannot see why that holds. If it is, I think that would complete my proof. I was looking for a relation between these two balls.

Comment: It holds by linearity.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I cannot see why $T(B(y,ε))=Τ(y+B(ε))$

Comment: Because $B(y,\varepsilon) = y + B(\varepsilon)$. That is trivial.

Comment: Ooo I misunderstood the symbols. I am very sorry. Indeed it is trivial. So the question becomes $T(B(y,ε))$ is bounded $\Longrightarrow T(B(ε))$ is bounded?

Comment: There is no question anymore: $T(B(\varepsilon)) = T(B(y,\varepsilon)) - Ty$ is, of course, bounded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56472/discussion-between-livaditis-alex-and-friedrich-philipp).

Comment: I am there. Where yre you?